# Regular Expression to match date

Tags: regex

How can I use regular expression to extract date from a string as below ?

CCBS_Call_History_.20-NOV-12.txt_RO.gz

Excepted output:
20-NOV-12

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/\d+\-[A-Z]+\-\d+/
```

will do the trick for you

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will work.

```
\d{1,2}\-[A-Z]{3}\-\d{1,2}
```

Here's an explanation.

```
\d{1,2} - One to two digits
\-      - Followed by a dash
[A-Z]{3}- Followed by 3 uppercase characters(JAN, FEB, NOV, DEC)
\-      - Followed by a dash
\d{1,2} - Followed by one to two digits
```

You can tweak this to include perhaps lowercase characters, 4 digit years or any of your other needs.